# Error to build app in Xcode 14.2 using macOS Sonoma

Tags: xcode, react-native, macos, build, x86-64

I'm using macOS Sonoma and XCode 14.2 (the current project only builds successfully using this version).

If I build using the terminal, the build runs successfully and works, but if I try to build from within XCode, my build returns an error.

Command in the terminal:
`xcodebuild ARCHS=x86_64 -workspace WorkdpaceName.xcworkspace -scheme WorkspaceScheme -destination "id={SIMULATOR ID}" build`

After that, if I go to XCode and do Product > Perform Action > Run Without Build, it runs my build smoothly.

If I go to XCode and do `Product > Build For > Running`, it returns the following error:
`Showing Recent Errors Only .../Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XCFrameworkIntermediates/MCISDKKit/MerciKit.framework/Modules/MerciKit.swiftmodule/x86_64-apple-ios-simulator.swiftinterface:4:8: Could not find module 'Alamofire' for target 'x86_64-apple-ios-simulator'; found: arm64-apple-ios-simulator, at: .../Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Alamofire/Alamofire.framework/Modules/Alamofire.swiftmodule`

I can't run in Rosetta mode because to open XCode, I run the command:
`arch -x86_64 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode`

I've also tried running the Simulator with the command:
`arch -x86_64 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/Simulator`

The above attempt didn't help.

Does anyone have an alternative for me to build from within XCode?

I appreciate in advance for anyone who tries to help <3

I've already tried changing the option within Build Settings to "Build Active Architecture Only" to "Yes."
I've tried running the Simulator beforehand, forcing it as "arch x86_64."
I've also attempted to complete the entire process through the terminal and then go to XCode and run only the Build (without deleting the Build folder and also deleting it).

Answer (score 1):

Starting with MacOS Sonoma version, Xcode 14.2 is not officially supported.